# HTML 5 - Section - Div - Header - can a div be placed between section and header?

Tags: html, header

I have this section and, for layout proposes I would need two divs inside that section. Of of them, should wrap the header part of section.

So:

```
<section>
 <div id="layout-stuff">
  <header>
    <h1>This is the section header</h1>
  </header>
  ...
 </div>
</section>
```

**Is this ok?**

Comment: As far as i know, you are not allowed to put the header inside a section. But you would be allowed to put a footer inside.
|EDIT: OK, according to this link, you are allowed to do so: http://www.anthonycalzadilla.com/2010/08/html5-section-aside-header-nav-footer-elements-not-as-obvious-as-they-sound/

Comment: I think using header is fine: http://orderedlist.com/resources/html-css/structural-tags-in-html5/

Comment: Not according to any link ;) : http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-header-element - here it clearly states that the header can be used inside a section. No issues there. :)

Comment: My Link from above says the following: 'Used for grouping together thematically-related content.' Why do you want do use a div? Why not using an article-tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. a `<div>` is nothing more than an element to hook styles with.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the header tag definition on w3schools it says:

"Note: A  tag cannot be placed within a footer, address or another header element."

So, it does not seem to be any of this cases. My guess It's fine to do it.

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_header.asp